Почему контейнер pg_admin не хочет подключаться к postgres в контейнере?
У меня есть docker-compose файл:
version: "3.9"

services:

  postgres:
    image: postgres:14
    restart: always
    environment:
      POSTGRES_PASSWORD: postgres
      PGDATA: /var/lib/postgresql/data
    ports:
      - 5432:5432
    volumes:
      - ./data:/var/lib/postgresql/data
    networks:
      - postgres

  pgadmin4:
    image: dpage/pgadmin4:latest
    restart: always
    environment:
      PGADMIN_DEFAULT_EMAIL: postgres@postgres.com
      PGADMIN_DEFAULT_PASSWORD: postgres
    ports:
      - 5050:80
    networks:
      - postgres
networks:
  postgres:
    driver: bridge

После запуска, pgadmin не может подключиться к postgres-контейнеру, при этом подключается к любым другим. В тоже время к postgres контейнеру подключается любой локальный клиент(dbviewer) кроме почему-то этого pgadmin (который в контейнере).
Падает ошибка при создании соединения:


Адрес сервера указывайте правильно.

смысле ip-адресом? ошибка та же

Каждый контейнер в docker-compose.yaml стартует как отдельный узел в виртуальной сети. Этим узлам назначаются имена, по умолчанию имя равно имени сервиса. База у вас записана как сервис postgres, поэтому виртуальный сервис тоже именуется postgres. Вот это имя и указывайте вместо localhost

@PakUula Спасибо, это помогло. Проблема решена. Но всё же, почему другие клиенты, например adminis, в том же контейнере подключаются, а pgadmin нет?

Каждый контейнер - это изолированный компьютер в компьютере. Если программы работают в одном сервисе, то они находятся в одном контейнере и видят друг друга через Unix сокеты или localhost. Если же в разных, то только через виртуальную сеть. localhost у каждого сервиса свой.

@PakUula большое спасибо!
